# Is the term "STL" still in use?

Tags: c++, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s this STL vs. “C++ Standard Library” fight all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-this-stl-vs-c-standard-library-fight-all-about)

Is the term STL still valid?  In other words, when I talk about an `std::vector`, is it correctly referred to as being something in the Standard Template Library, the C++ Standard Library, or both?

Comment: I'd say "STL". "Standard Library" may refer to stdlib.h.

Comment: In general, the C++ standard library is correct, unless you are actually using an `std::vector` class from an STL implementation. I find `STL` confusing because I don't remember exactly which parts of the `STL` eventually made it into the C++ standard library.

Comment: @juanchopanza: A vector class from an STL implementation is not in namespace `std` ;)